# MongoEngine and GridFS - Write files with ImageGridFsProxy

Tags: image, store, mongoengine, gridfs

I'm playing around with mongoengine(0.8.2) and trying to write some images using the GridFS functionality. This is how I have declared my model:

```
class Lady(DynamicDocument):
    id = ObjectIdField()
    name = StringField()
    offers = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Offer))
    pictures = ListField(ImageField())
```

So what I want to do is to append the pictures to the pictures field. What I tried is the following:

```
fileA = open('/home/evermean/Pictures/a.jpg', 'r')
fileB = open('/home/evermean/Pictures/b.jpg', 'r')
upload = [fileA, fileB]

    files = []
    for f in upload:
        mf = ImageGridFsProxy()
        mf.put(f, content_type = 'image/jpeg')
        files.append(mf)
    lady.pictures = files
    lady.save()
```

What I get is the following:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/evermean/Code/django/pourlamour/core/tests.py", line 38, in test_basic_addition
mf.put(f, content_type = 'image/jpeg')
File "/home/evermean/Code/django/env/pourlamour/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 1257, in put
field = self.instance._fields[self.key]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_fields'
```

I tried to figure out what goes wrong and the following line from the fields.py seems to be responsible although I cannot quite see what to do about it.

```
field = self.instance._fields[self.key]
```

I also tried to use the GridFSProxy which works ... so why does it fail with ImageGridFsProxy?

Any ideas? Where is my mistake? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I did the same it works with GridFsProxy so i used FileField instead of ImageField. Let me know if you got any solution for it.